# Chrome extension to 'find' multiple words and phrases

Tags: gratis, chrome, text-search

I am looking for a Chrome extension that allows me to find multiple words.

There is the 'find in page' built-in, but that only allows me to such for one word, and if I search for more than 1, they must be in succession - which I don't want.

What I do want:

- search and highlight multiple words / phrases on current page
- words don't have to be in succession
- must be Chrome extension - I need to use it on Windows and OSX
- need it to be free

Desirable:

- customizable highlighting colour
- shortcut key to activate extension
- wildcard characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Regex Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/regex-search/bcdabfmndggphffkchfdcekcokmbnkjl)

Regex search is a Chrome extension to search webpages by [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). To use it based on your requirement just separate the words by the "or" character, `|`. The dot `.` can be used as a wild card.

Features:

- Search and highlight multiple words / phrases
- Words don't have to be in succession
- Is a Chrome extension
- Is free and open-source
- Has a shortcut key <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Has wildcard characters

It does not allow to customize the highlight color, but the developer is open to suggestions. Also, since it's open-source, we could take a look under the hood and see if the color can be changed. (**Edit:** this is indeed possible as pointed out in the comments by ComFreek.)

---

Here is an example where I searched the question for "word", "free", and all two letter words starting with "i".

Syntax:

```
word|i. |free
```

[image]

<sup>(Edit: Reduced picture size and moved it to the bottom since it was disctracting. Click it for higher res version)</sup>

Comment: The general search results' color is determined by the user agent style for `<mark>` tags. The color for the currently selected search result can be changed [in the source](https://github.com/gsingh93/regex-search/blob/master/src/content/content.css). (Disclaimer: I contributed some changes some months ago.)

Comment: According to Schmibby this does not work with frames.